# CÁLCULO UTILIZANDO FUNÇÃO DENTRO DE FUNÇÃO - JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html5, funções

Boa tarde, estou com um problema em que não consigo obter o resultado final. O programa é o seguinte: o usuário ira digitar os valores, a operação que deseja(soma ou subtração), e o programa irá realizar o restante.

Estou aprendendo função, e por isso gostaria de realizar este cálculo utilizando funções (soma e subtração) dentro de outra função principal (cálculo).
Desde já, grato!

```
var n1 = prompt('Digite o primeiro número:')
var n2 = prompt('Digite o segundo número:')

n1 = parseInt(n1)
n2 = parseInt(n2)

var operacao = prompt('Digite a operação que você deseja(soma ou subtração)')

function calculo(n1,n2, operacao){

    if (operacao == 'soma') {
        callbackSoma(n1,n2)

    }else if(operacao == 'subtracao') {
        callbackSubtracao(n1,n2)

    }else{
        document.write('Digite uma operação válida')
    }
}

function callbackSoma(n1,n2){
    return resultado = n1+n2 
}

function callbackSubtracao(n1,n2){
    return resultado = n1-n2
}

document.write('o resultado final foi de: ' +calculo(n1,n2,operacao))
```

Comment: Dentro das funções callbackEtc vc só precisa retornar o valor. Ex: `return n1+n2` (em vez de `return resultado = n1+n2`, que é desnecessário), e na função `calculo` vc precisa retornar também: `return callbackSoma(n1,n2)` em vez de apenas `callbackSoma(n1,n2)`. E coloque ponto-e-vírgula no final das linhas. Pode parecer "frescura", mas isso evita algumas situações bizarras que podem ocorrer se você não usá-los, como [essa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1169596) e [essa](/q/432960/112052) (veja mais sobre isso [aqui](/q/3341/112052)).

Comment: a sim, muito obrigado!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Faltou apenas um detalhezinho para funcionar, o return dentro do metodo `calculo`

```
var n1 = prompt('Digite o primeiro número:')
var n2 = prompt('Digite o segundo número:')

n1 = parseInt(n1)
n2 = parseInt(n2)

var operacao = prompt('Digite a operação que você deseja(soma ou subtração)')

function calculo(n1,n2, operacao){

    if (operacao == 'soma') {
        return callbackSoma(n1,n2)

    }else if(operacao == 'subtracao') {
        return callbackSubtracao(n1,n2)

    }else{
        document.write('Digite uma operação válida')
    }
}

function callbackSoma(n1,n2){
    return resultado = n1+n2 
}

function callbackSubtracao(n1,n2){
    return resultado = n1-n2
}

document.write('o resultado final foi de: ' +calculo(n1,n2,operacao))
```

Comment: Ah sim, muito obrigado Thiago!

Answer (score 0):

Você não precisa dos parâmetros na função, essas entradas já são definidas no `prompt`

OBS: o código a seguir evita o retorno do tipo `Digite uma operação válidao resultado final foi de: undefined` ou do tipo `o resultado final foi de: NaN` caso alguma entrada no `prompt` seja nula

```js
var n1 = parseInt(prompt("Digite um número qualquer"));
var n2 = parseInt(prompt("Digite outro número qualquer"));
var operacao = prompt('Digite a operação que você deseja(soma ou subtração)');
var total;

  function calculo() {
    if (operacao =="subtracao") {
        return callbackSubtracao(total);
    } else if(operacao =="soma"){
        return callbackSoma(total);
    }else{
      return('Digite uma operação válida')
    }

  }

  function callbackSubtracao(total) {
    return "o resultado final foi de: " +(n1-n2);
  }

  function callbackSoma(total) {
    return "o resultado final foi de: " +(n1+n2);
  }


  console.log(calculo())
```